# Heroku troubleshoots LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rspec, tdd

It's **Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial Chapter 7** 
When I'm trying deploy my project on Heroku:

```
$ git push heroku
```

It gives me that error:

```
 LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/rails
```

So, what I should do, if you know please help me with this issue.

Comment: I believe this is a rbenv issue. Run `rbenv rehash` and then retry your command.